# Adding files to .tar from directory

Tags: command-line, directory, tar

Is there a way to add files to .tar file in one directory from an another directory? And at the same time list the content of the tar to see if its added.

I only found ways to add files if its in the same folder, not outside it.

I am a bit stuck here and maybe the answer is obvious, but I cant get it right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tar`'s option `-C`/`--directory` to first change to a directory and then process the specified files. You can specify `-C` followed by a file  multiple:

```
$ mkdir a b c
$ touch a/1 a/2 b/3
$ cd c
$ tar cvf ../all.tar -C ../a 1 2 -C ../b 3
1
2
3
```

Or do if you don't want to specify each file under `a` and `b` separately:
`tar cvf ../all2.tar -C ../a . -C ../b .`

Comment: What are the dots for? If I am currently in the folder in which is the archive, and the file to add is in another, do I have to use `..`?

Comment: @c023 You just have to specify the path to the directory. Are you sure you specify  `-r` if you want to add to an existing tar archive.

Comment: So how would look the full command with the adding? Can you use `myfile.tar` for the existing tar, `othersource` for the path of the other file I want to add? Its a bit confusing for me as an beginner.

Comment: @c023 Please extend your question with the directory tree with the tar file and and (some of) the files you want to add.